# Read in multiple lines from standard input with arguments in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to read in multiple lines from standard input in Haskell, plus one argument, then do something with the current line and write something to the standard output.

In my case I am trying to normalize lambda expressions. The program may receive 1 or more lambda expressions to normalize and then it has to write the result (normalized form or error) to the standard output. And the program may receive an argument (the max number of reductions). Here is the main function:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  params <- getArgs
  fullLambda <- getLine
  let lambda = convertInput fullLambda
  let redNum | (length params) == 1 = read (head params)
             | otherwise = 100
  case (parsing lambda) of
    Left  errorExp -> putStrLn ("ERROR: " ++ lambda)
    Right lambdaExp -> do
      let normalizedLambdaExp = reduction lambdaExp redNum
      if (isNormalForm normalizedLambdaExp) && (isClosed lambdaExp)
        then putStrLn ("OK: " ++ show normalizedLambdaExp)
        else putStrLn ("ERROR: " ++ lambda)
  where
    convertInput :: String -> String
    convertInput ('\"':xs) = take ((length xs) - 2) xs
    convertInput input = input
```

So this code handles one line and completes the reductions and then writes something to the standard output. How can I change this to handle multiple lines? I've read about *replicateM* but I can't seem to grasp it. My mind is very OO so I was thinking maybe some looping somehow, but that is surely not the preferred way.

Also, this program has to be able to run like this:

```
echo "(\x.x) (\x.x)" | Main 25
```

And will produce:

```
OK: (\x.x)
```

And if there are multiple lines, it has to produce the same kind of output for each line, in new lines.

But also has to work without the argument, and has to handle multiple lines. I spent time on google and here, but I'm not sure how the argument reading will happen. I need to read in the argument once and the line(s) once or many times. Does someone know a not too lengthy solution to this problem?

I've tried it like this, too (imperatively):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  params <- getArgs
  mainHelper params
  main

mainHelper :: [String] -> IO ()
mainHelper params = do
  fullLambda <- getLine
```

And so on, but then it puts this to the standard output as well:

```
Main: <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you say you want it to handle many lines, do you mean the lines will have separate expressions, which are separately handled, perhaps with interleaving some interaction with the program, or do you just mean you want to be able to handle a text which may have many newlines? If the latter, you just use `fmap lines getContents`, which will accept material from stdin up til EOF and deliver a list of separate lines. (It is probably better to use `Data.Text.IO.getContents` for this, by the way.)

Comment: Sorry, I got rid of the first version since it was ungrammatical, but then reverted it... But, to return, is the idea that each lambda entered will immediately be followed by a response, until EOF?

Comment: @Michael So, if there are say 5 lambda expressions, one in each line, then I would see 5 response lines after the input lines. Enter 1 line > print 1 line. Enter 5 lines > print 5 lines.

Comment: @Michael And since we're talking functional languages here, I think all the input will be read into a string and then split somehow. And then I would have to process the lines one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you want to:

1. Parse a command line option which may or may not exist.
2. For each line of input process it with some function.

Here is an approach using lazy IO:

```
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad

main = do args <- getArgs
          let option = case args of
                         []    -> ... the default value...
                         (a:_) -> read a

          contents <- getContents
          forM_ (lines contents) $ \aline -> do
            process option aline
```

I am assuming your processing function has type `process :: Int -> String -> IO ()`. For instance, it could look like:

```
process :: Int -> String -> IO ()
process option str = do
  if length str < option
    then putStrLn $ "OK: " ++ str
    else putStrLn $ "NOT OK: line too long"
```

Here's how it works:

1. `contents <- getContents` reads all of standard input into the variable `contents`
2. `lines contents` breaks up the input into lines
3. `forM_ ...` iterates over each line, passing the line to the `process` function

The trick is that `getContents` reads standard input lazily so that you'll get some output after each line is read.

You should be aware that there are issues with lazy IO which you may run into when your program becomes more complex. However, for this simple use case lazy IO is perfectly fine and works well.

Comment: Excellent answer and explanation! Very educational. Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!